# The requested resource is not available Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M17

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I have a problem when I run my work in server tomcat I have an error :
"The requested resource is not available"
 I want to insert user to my table that exist in PHPMyAdmin
my table columns are : userId, description, dueDate, done
(I create todolist) in JavaEE

this is my User.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping> 
    <class name="il.ac.shenkar.User" table="users">
        <id name="id" type="int" column="ID" >
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <property type="string" name="userName">
            <column name="userName"/>
        </property>

        <property type="string" name="password">
            <column name="password"/>
        </property>
        <property type="string" name="email">
            <column name="email"/>
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

this is my Controller:

```
package il.ac.shenkar;

public class Controller extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Controller() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HibernateToDoListDAO DAO = HibernateToDoListDAO.getInstance();
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = null;
        HttpSession userSession = request.getSession();
        String path = request.getQueryString();
        try{
            if(path.endsWith("addItem")){
                dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/additem.jsp");
            }
            else if(path.endsWith("logout")){
                userSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(0);
                Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
                if (cookies != null) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {

                        Cookie cookie = cookies[i];
                        cookies[i].setValue(null);
                        cookies[i].setMaxAge(0);
                        response.addCookie(cookie);
                    }
                }
                dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.html");
            }
            else if (path.endsWith("deleteUser")) {
                userSession = request.getSession();
                int userId = Integer.valueOf((String) userSession.getAttribute("userId"));
                ArrayList<Item> items = DAO.getItems(userId);
                for(Item i: items){
                    DAO.deleteItem(i.getId());
                }
                DAO.deleteUser(userId);
                Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
                if (cookies != null) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {

                        Cookie cookie = cookies[i];
                        cookies[i].setValue(null);
                        cookies[i].setMaxAge(0);
                        response.addCookie(cookie);
                    }
                }
                userSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(0);
                dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.html");
            }
            else if (path.endsWith("changePass")){
                dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/passchange.jsp");
            }
            else if(path.endsWith("accountSettings")){
                dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/account.jsp");
            }
            else if(path.endsWith("update")){
                String itemId = (String)request.getParameter("itemId");
                dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/itemsettings.jsp");
            }
            else if(path.endsWith("backToHome")){
                userSession = request.getSession();
                int userId = Integer.valueOf((String) userSession.getAttribute("userId"));
                User user = null;
                try {
                    user = DAO.getUser(userId);
                } catch (ToDoException e) {
                    request.setAttribute("exception", e.getMessage());
                    dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/error.jsp");
                }
                Cookie cookie = new Cookie("userName", user.getUserName());
                cookie.setMaxAge(60 * 30);
                response.addCookie(cookie);
                ArrayList<Item> items =  DAO.getItems(user.getId());
                request.setAttribute("user", user);
                request.setAttribute("items", items);
                dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/home.jsp");
            }
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        } catch (ToDoException e){
            request.setAttribute("exception", e.getMessage());
            dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/error.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HibernateToDoListDAO DAO = HibernateToDoListDAO.getInstance();
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = null;
        HttpSession userSession = null;
        String userId = null;
        String location = null;
        String action = request.getParameter("action");
        try {
            if(action.equals("Sign in")){               
                String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
                String password = request.getParameter("password");
                ArrayList<User> users = DAO.getUsers();
                User user = null;
                for(User u: users){
                    if(u.getUserName().equals(userName) && u.getPassword().equals(password)){
                        u.setAuth(true);
                        user = u;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (user != null && user.isAuth()){                 
                    userId = String.valueOf(user.getId());
                    location = "home";
                    userSession = request.getSession();
                    userSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(-1);
                    userSession.setAttribute("userId", userId);
                    Cookie cookie = new Cookie("userName", user.getUserName());
                    cookie.setMaxAge(60 * 30);
                    response.addCookie(cookie);
                    ArrayList<Item> items =  DAO.getItems(user.getId());
                    //user.setItemCount(DAO.getItemCount(user.getId()));
                    request.setAttribute("user", user);
                    request.setAttribute("items", items);
                    dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/home.jsp");
                    dispatcher.forward(request, response);

                }
                else{
                    throw new ToDoException("User not authenticated");
                }
            }
            else if(action.equals("Sign up")){
                String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
                String password = request.getParameter("password");
                String email = request.getParameter("email");
                User newUser = new User(userName, password,email);
                ArrayList<User> users = DAO.getUsers();
                for(User u: users){
                    if(newUser.getUserName().equals(u.getUserName())){
                        throw new ToDoException("User already exists");                 
                    }
                }   
                DAO.addUser(newUser);
                userSession = request.getSession();
                userSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(30 * 60);
                userId = String.valueOf(newUser.getId());
                Cookie cookie = new Cookie("userName", newUser.getUserName());
                cookie.setMaxAge(60 * 30);
                response.addCookie(cookie);
                ArrayList<Item> items =  DAO.getItems(newUser.getId());
                request.setAttribute("user", newUser);
                request.setAttribute("items", items);
                userSession.setAttribute("userId", userId);
                dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/home.jsp");
                dispatcher.forward(request, response);

            }

            else if(action.equals("updateItemDone")){
                userSession = request.getSession();
                userId = (String) userSession.getAttribute("userId");
                String itemName = request.getParameter("desc");
                String itemDueDate = request.getParameter("date");
                String itemId = request.getParameter("itemId");
                Item item = new Item(Integer.parseInt(userId),itemName,itemDueDate,1);
                item.setDueDate(itemDueDate);
                item.setId(Integer.parseInt(itemId));
                DAO.updateItem(item, item.getId());
                User user = DAO.getUser(Integer.parseInt(userId));
                Cookie cookie = new Cookie("userName", user.getUserName());
                cookie.setMaxAge(60 * 30);
                response.addCookie(cookie);
                ArrayList<Item> items =  DAO.getItems(user.getId());
                //user.setItemCount(DAO.getItemCount(user.getId()));
                request.setAttribute("user", user);
                request.setAttribute("items", items);
                dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/home.jsp");
            }
            else if(action.equals("changeAccount")){
                userSession = request.getSession();
                userId = (String) userSession.getAttribute("userId");
                location = "home";
                String fullName = request.getParameter("fullName");
                String email = request.getParameter("email");
                User user = DAO.getUser(Integer.parseInt(userId));
                //user.setFullName(fullName);
                user.setEmail(email);
                //DAO.updateUser(user);
                Cookie cookie = new Cookie("userName", user.getUserName());
                cookie.setMaxAge(60 * 30);
                response.addCookie(cookie);
                ArrayList<Item> items =  DAO.getItems(user.getId());
                //user.setItemCount(DAO.getItemCount(user.getId()));
                request.setAttribute("user", user);
                request.setAttribute("items", items);
                dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/home.jsp");
                dispatcher.forward(request, response);
            }
            else if(action.equals("delete")){//delete item
                userSession = request.getSession();
                userId = (String) userSession.getAttribute("userId");
                int itemId = Integer.parseInt((String) request.getParameter("itemId"));             
                Item item = DAO.getItem(itemId);
                DAO.deleteItem(item.getId());   
                User user = DAO.getUser(Integer.parseInt(userId));
                Cookie cookie = new Cookie("userName", user.getUserName());
                cookie.setMaxAge(60 * 30);
                response.addCookie(cookie);
                ArrayList<Item> items =  DAO.getItems(user.getId());
                request.setAttribute("user", user);
                request.setAttribute("items", items);
                dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/home.jsp");
            }
            else if(action.equals("update")){
                String itemId = (String)request.getParameter("itemId");
                request.setAttribute("item", itemId);
                dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/itemsettings.jsp");
            }
            else if(action.equals("done")){ //item is done
                userSession = request.getSession();
                String itemName = request.getParameter("itemName");
                String itemDate = request.getParameter("itemDate");
                userId = (String) userSession.getAttribute("userId");
                //int userId, String description, String date, int done
                Item item = new Item(Integer.parseInt(userId),itemName,itemDate,1);
                item.setDueDate(itemDate);                  
                DAO.addItem(item);
                User user = DAO.getUser(Integer.parseInt(userId));
                Cookie cookie = new Cookie("userName", user.getUserName());
                cookie.setMaxAge(60 * 30);
                response.addCookie(cookie);
                ArrayList<Item> items =  DAO.getItems(user.getId());
                request.setAttribute("user", user);
                request.setAttribute("items", items);
                dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/home.jsp");
            }
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
           // response.sendRedirect("PageController?userId=" + userId + "&where=" + location);
        } catch (ToDoException e){
            request.setAttribute("exception", e.getMessage());
            dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/error.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }   
    }
}
```

this is my client side (addUser.jsp):

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=windows-1255"
    pageEncoding="windows-1255"%>
<% Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    double time = 0;
    if(cookies != null) {
        for(Cookie cookie : cookies){
            if(cookie.getName().equals("userName")){
                time = Double.parseDouble(cookie.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1255">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
         <section>
            <h1>add new user</h1>
            <h4>Please enter your details:</h4>
            <form method="post" action="Controller?action=create">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">User name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter user name" name="email" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter password" name="password" required>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
            </form>
        </section>
</body>
</html>
```

What I need to do to fix this problem?
Thanks,

Comment: can you post your error please?

Comment: @YCF_L HTTP Status 404 - /toDoNew/Controller


type Status report

message /toDoNew/Controller

description The requested resource is not available.


Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M17